# Add/Change channel for handler at runtime

Tags: python, circuits-framework

In circuits 3.1.0, is there a way to set at runtime the channel for a handler?
An useful alternative would be to add a handler at runtime and specify the channel.

I've checked the Manager.addHandler implementation but couldn't make it work. I tried:

```
self._my_method.__func__.channel = _my_method_channel
self._my_method.__func__.names = ["event name"]
self.addHandler(self._my_method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is; however it's not really a publically exposed API.

**Example:** (*of creating event handlers at runtime*)

```
@handler("foo")
def on_foo(self):
    return "Hello World!"


def test_addHandler():
    m = Manager()
    m.start()

    m.addHandler(on_foo)
```

This is taken from [tests.core.test_dynamic_handlers](https://github.com/circuits/circuits/blob/16d52a1157bae28325c9e2b497450b47667315a9/tests/core/test_dynamic_handlers.py)

**NB:** Every `BaseComponent`/`Component` subclass is also a subclass of `Manager` and has the `.addHandler()` and `.removeHandler()` methods. You can also set the `@handler()` dynamically like this:

```
def on_foo(...):
    ...

self.addHandler(handler("foo")(on_foo))
```

You can also see a *good* example of this in the library itself with [circuits.io.process](https://github.com/circuits/circuits/blob/16d52a1157bae28325c9e2b497450b47667315a9/circuits/io/process.py) where we dynamically create event handlers for stdin, stdout and stderr.

Comment: Great! thank you. For the sake of completeness, I must say that these work only with free functions (and alike), not with instance methods (which, of course, can be workarounded by using lambdas)

Comment: Yes; ``.addHandler()`` expects a function decorated with ``handler()`` and then binds this to the component.